# Is $2$ not a prime (in $\Bbb R$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Considering the definitions of irreducible and prime elements in an integral domain $R$ and knowing the fact

> Every Field is an integral domain

Does it mean 2 is not a prime in $\mathbb{R}$?

Since, for 2 to be a prime element in $\mathbb{R}$, it has to be a non-unit element. But, 2 is a unit.

Comment: You should distinguish between $R$ and $\Bbb R$. Do you mean $2$ is not a prime in the field of real numbers?

Comment: There are no prime elements in any field.

Comment: Correct. $2$ is not a prime in $\Bbb{R}$ because $\Bbb{R}$ is a field. Fields don't have any primes. $2$ is a prime in $\Bbb{Z}$ though, which is what we mean, when we call $2$ a prime.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Then how do we assert the fact, that indeed 2 is a prime in \Bbb{R}? Is there anyway we can do it?

Comment: Who asserted that? No one I trust, surely :-) When most people discuss prime numbers, it is a safe bet that they discuss primes in $\Bbb{Z}$. Later in your studies exceptions come up. For example when you get into rings of algebraic integers. But at that point the need to mention the ring is everywhere, and people become more careful.

Answer (score 4):

Ring theory is very boring in fields, since, as you mention, every non-zero element is a unit. It does follow as you say that there are no primes in a field, simply because there are no non-units other than zero.

Comment: @Bernard Right, fixed.

Comment: Very succinct! I think this is a good way to explain / understand it. If the OP is interested in moving on in algebra, they may want to go on to read about prime ideals and how they correspond to prime elements in Principal Ideal Domains.

Comment: Ring theory is certainly *not* boring in fields, but *divisibility* theory is.